# How to inherit the behaviour of polymer elements to custom element in polymer 1.x

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, custom-element

I need to use paper-range-slider element with displayFunction callback to customize the display content in slider.

In paper-range-selector v1.3 version support this feature, but it requires at least polymer v2.x, where as my polymer version is v1.3(paper-range-selector v0.2.7 is supported for this polymer version but displayFunction feature is not supported in it).

So i am trying to create custom-slider-element where it uses the paper-range-selector(v0.2.7) elements and add displayFunction feature and custom-slider-element can be used in my application.

Could any one tell me how to import behaviour of paper-range-slider to custom-slider-element? So that all the properties and methods added to custom-slider-element should directly pass to paper-range-selector.

Comment: could you please provide a sample how your custom-slider-element looks right now (html/css/js) ?

Comment: <pre><dom-module id="custom-slider">
    <template>
        <paper-range-slider id="slider"></paper-range-slider>
    </template>
    <script>
            Polymer({
                is: "custom-slider",
                properties: {
                    test: {
                        type: Object,
                        value: {}
                    }
                },
                ready: function() {
                    this.behaviors = this.$.slider.behaviors;
                }
            });
    </script>
</dom-module></pre>

Comment: this is how mu current custom-slider element looks like.
Basically when to import properties and behavior of paper-range-selector.
For ex:
<custom-slider min="10" max="100"></custom-slider>
then it should directly add these properties to paper-range-slider like 
<paper-range-slider min="10" max="100"></paper-range-slider>
and there should not be any mapping of each properties and methods inside <custom-slider>